# How to get the last character(s) of a single, specified, line of a multiline text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

Let's say I have a multiline text that fills some `<div>` element. Is it possible, and if so – how – to get the last character of a specified line?

For example after wrapping inside a div a text becomes:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
Aenean dignissim convallis
lorem ut rhoncus. Duis metus
nulla, aliquet quis pharetra.
```

I am interested in what is the last character of the line 4 which is the letter "s". Or I am interested in 3 last characters of the same line, which reads "tus".

But how could I find this in JS?

What is more – how could I style those returned letters?

EDIT

No, I can not put that into an array. The div is of unknown size (responsive) and thus I have no a priori idea where the line breaks appear.

Comment: put these lines inside an array and then using loop you can achieve that.

Comment: @Dcoder The text does not have an internal structure, it is filled into the div and the line break positions depend on the font size, font face and the width of the div. Thus the text can not be a priori put into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can put these lines in an array and then loop through the lines and get required number of characters.

Here I am getting line-4's last 3 characters where variable line and numberOfChars indicate line number and required number of characters from last respectively.

```js
let array = [ "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
              "consectetur adipiscing elit",
              "Aenean dignissim convallis",
              "lorem ut rhoncus. Duis metus",
              "nulla, aliquet quis pharetra."
           ]
           
let line = 4;
let numberOfChars = 3;

array.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index+1 === line) {
    console.log(item.slice(-numberOfChars));
  }
});
```

Comment: I can not put that into an array because I have no idea where the lines break. The text is filled into the div automatically, depending on the font face and size and the div size.